# How to do this vertical navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to do a vertical navigation bar from this codepen
http://codepen.io/bronsrobin/pen/GAlfg
but i only need the navigation bar nothing else
i tried to copy the html related to the navigation bar but nothing happened
you can check my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/922ug/

```
html

    <aside>
      <a class="current">Home</a>
      <a>Users</a>
      <a>Schedule</a>
      <a>Info</a>
    </aside>
```

look on the js fiddle to understand.

can anybody fix it for me please and tell me whats the problem?

Comment: any fix for my problem?

Comment: Beautiful menu, i'm looking over it. Hold on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your JSFiddle code.

## 1: Your are using SCSS where normal CSS is expected

All your CSS lines affecting color are actually written in SCSS code.

SCSS (Sassy CSS) is a CSS preprocessor language, it enables you write CSS with a few extra features that are not normally not allowed (such as the use of variables and calculations); when you save it, a program converts/compiles it into a standard CSS file.

But rarely should you enter straight SCSS into a browser. In this case, it must be converted to regular CSS first (note that the CodePen example specifically says "CSS (SCSS)" at the top, so CodePen is automatically doing this compiling; JSFiddle is not).

For example, this SCSS line in your JSFiddle:

```
  background-color: $black;
```

It uses a variable, $black. CSS will not understand this. Using the CodePen example's color variables at the top, the CSS line would normally be compiled to:

```
  background-color: #171616;
```

Which is perfectly valid normal CSS.

Here's the fully-compiled CSS you need:

```
aside {
  width: 17%;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #171616;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  float: left;      
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
aside a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s linear,
              border-right-color .3s linear,
              color .3s linear;
  color: #808080;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
aside a:hover,
aside a.current { 
  background-color: #1D1B1B;
  border-right-color: #FDCC1C;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

## 2: You are using a jQuery script but did not add the jQuery library to your code

This keeps the code from successfully running. In JSFiddle, you can add the library by using the drop-down menus on the far-left.

The revised menu solving both issues can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/922ug/1/

Comment: i added the jquery code in a file named jquery.js
i added in the head section this <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
this is right?